# Extending ManagedPerformanceCounter

Tags: apache-camel

I have been trying to add my own performance counter, and I'm unable to use this performance counter for my routes.

Could anyone tell me how to use a custom performance counter instead of ManagedPerformanceCounter?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for a JMX solution...you can register a processor and use custom APIs to retrieve stats...

http://camel.apache.org/why-is-my-processor-not-showing-up-in-jconsole.html

also, here are some notes on using JMX to retrieve route stats...

http://benoday.blogspot.com/2010/08/managing-camel-routes-with-jmx-apis.html